# Get Docker tag based on digest?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

Talking about GCR specifically, but since it's just a docker registry, probably the question should apply globally

I have a resourceUrl from grafeas in the form of:

`https://eu.gcr.io/projectId/image@sha256:c6f84183f9605cfb16c489dbbf2aed19304288c820f0b233d92d0e98de65d899`

How do I get the tag for this digest `sha256:c6f84183f9605cfb16c489dbbf2aed19304288c820f0b233d92d0e98de65d899` ?

the only applicable(?) endpoint on docker v2 API is `/v2/<name>/manifests/<reference>` but the returned manifest does not have tag info.

Of course I could use `/v2/<name>/tags/list` ant loop through all tags to match with digest, but that seems very suboptimal

Answer (score 2):

There's not currently an easy way to do this via the registry API.

GCR (currently) returns a mapping from digest to tags in the `/tags/list` response, for example, this works using `curl` and `jq` on a public repo:

```
$ curl -s https://gcr.io/v2/google-containers/cadvisor/tags/list | jq '.manifest["sha256:b3b01b12dd15699e818c2c54160d48e0ea52bfab970e4ce7402e3dcb13ec82fa"].tag'
["latest", "v0.28.3"]
```

This behavior isn't really part of the spec, so it's subject to change, but it works for now.

Comment: Just stumbled on this. A big pity that `tags/list` does not specify to return at least the digest for a tag :-(